# Troubleshooting an image

Tags: image, resolution

I have an image, below, that seems "soft" and I'd like to know why.  Possibly it was resized from something like 3000 x 3000 and not sharpened. Possibly it's a 500 x 500 image originally, expanded to 960 x 960.  Is there a way to determine what's wrong with it?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll want to check the [image-processing tag at DSP StackExchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing).

Comment: Thanks.  I reposted over there: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/46514/troubleshooting-an-image.